# Removing strpos

Tags: php

How can I strip the last comma (second comma), I know how to locate it with strpos but not sure how to remove it.

```
$m_place = "New York, NY, 10011"; // New York, NY 10011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
$tmp = explode(",", $m_place)
$res = $tmp[0].", ".$tmp[1]." ".$tmp[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that the regex way too:

```
$m_place = str_replace("/,(?=[^,]+$)/", "", $m_place);
```

Answer (score 1):

The classical way is to cut out the two parts that the comma separates with `substr` and concatenate them:

```
$pos = strrpos($input, ',');
$input = substr($input, 0, $pos).substr($input, $pos + 1);
```

If you wanted to remove an *arbitrary occurrence* of the comma, one convenient way would be to use the evaluation capabilities of `preg_replace`:

```
$occ = 0; // which occurrence to remove? 0 = first
$i = 0; // need this for the line below

$input = preg_replace('/,/e', '$i++ == $num ? "" : ","', $input);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/goOak)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the character at that position to `''`

```
$m_place[$position] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the regexp way:

```
$m_place = preg_replace('/,([^,]+)$/','\1',$m_place);
```